# Looking for a Chewing Gum Monster

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I'm looking for something that scared the living daylights out of me as a child.  It was probably either a tv movie or an episode of show that ran in the early-to-mid nineties in the US.  It involved a monster made of chewing gum and a girl named Gabby in a paddle boat, trying to escape from the thing.  It was live action, probably geared toward older children.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was an episode of [Ghostwriter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostwriter_%28TV_series%29) called "Attack of the Slime Monster". It has a character named Gaby, and the gum monster is from a story the characters are writing.

This was a four-part episode, and in the second part the monster kidnaps Gaby and brings her across a lake in a boat. Her brother writes himself into the story, and follows across the lake in another boat trying to rescue her.

Comment: Wow.  I was four.  How on earth did I manage to get my mother to let me watch that?